# How does whileTrue: works in Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk

I want to know how `whileTrue:` works. I searched the implementation that is in `BlockClosure`:

```
whileTrue: aBlock 
    ^ [self value] whileTrue: [aBlock value]
```

And another implementation with no parameter:

```
whileTrue
    ^ [self value] whileTrue: []
```

But I don't know how that works, that's a recursive method, but this led me to ask several questions:

1. How does this recursive call terminate?
2. If `[self value]` returns a `Boolean` object, why is `whileTrue:` not implemented in the `Boolean` type?
3. Why is there another implementation named `whileTrue` that just do not receive any block and evaluates `self`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`whileTrue:` is inlined by the compiler, that's why you don't see the actual implementation. Here's the comment out of Pharo:

> "Ordinarily compiled in-line, and therefore not overridable.
>       This is in case the message is sent to other than a literal block.
>       Evaluate the argument, aBlock, as long as the value of the receiver is true."

If you look at the byte code of `#whileTrue:` you'll see that the compiler simply uses a jump to make the loop:

```
17 <70> self
18 <C9> send: value
19 <9C> jumpFalse: 25
20 <10> pushTemp: 0
21 <C9> send: value
22 <87> pop
23 <A3 F8> jumpTo: 17 <---- here's the jump
25 <7B> return: nil
```

`#whileTrue` is also inlined directly (slightly optimized byte code).
The inlining is also the reason why there's no implementation of this on `Boolean` (apart from the fact that there's no point in reevaluating a boolean...).

`#whileTrue` is there so that you can easily create endless loops the only terminate e.g. when the process terminates, a semaphore is signaled, an exception occurs etc.

Comment: How can you see the bytecode?

Comment: Which dialect / IDE are you using? In Pharo / Squeak there's a button next to the text area that you can press.

Comment: I'm using Squeak. I will search that button. Thanks.

Comment: In Squeak the button is the right most one above the text area, labelled "source". Click on it and then select "byteCodes".

Answer (score 3):

My Smalltalk is a bit rusty, and I don't have Smalltalk installed at the moment, so there might be some syntax errors in here, but you get the idea:

```
whileTrue: aBlock
    ↑ self value ifTrue: [aBlock value. self whileTrue: aBlock]
```

Here's a version in Ruby that I actually tested, of which the above (I hope) is a translation:

```
class Proc
  def vhile(block)
    self.().iff(thn: -> {block.(); vhile(block)})
  end
end
```

You need the following monkeypatches to get the Smalltalk-style conditionals to work:

```
class TrueClass
  def iff(thn:, els: ->{})
    thn.()
  end
end

class FalseClass
  def iff(thn:, els: ->{})
    els.()
  end
end
```